# Napping on Shabbos to stay up for Shavuos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, shavuos, hachana-prep-for-weekday

This years Shavuos falls out on Motzei Shabbos. The minhag for many Jews is to [stay up all night learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shavuot#All-night_Torah_study).

There is also a prohibition on Shabbos to prepare for after shabbos, this is called "[Hachono](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Hachana)".

May one nap on Shabbos to gain energy with the stated intention of staying up all night for Motzei Shabbos?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [very article you link to](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Hachana) answers the question!

> It's permissible to go to sleep on Shabbat in order to be awake after Shabbat, however, one shouldn’t say that one is doing so for that purpose. [Shemirat Shabbat KeHilchata 28:72]

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Eliezer Melamed in his Sefer Peninei Halacha discusses [this](http://ph.yhb.org.il/plus/12-02-12-04-2/):

> **ד – שינה בשבת לצורך ליל שבועות**
>
> ההלכה מפרק הלכה יב - יום טוב שחל במוצאי שבת, סוגיה ט - דיני ערב יום
>   טוב שחל בשבת.‏ קישור ישיר להלכה. ספר חסידים רסו: "בשבת לא יאמר אדם
>   נישן כדי שנעשה מלאכתינו במוצאי שבת, שאסור לומר למחר אעשה, ואפילו חפץ
>   לכתוב תורה, מפני שמראה מה שישן ונח בשבת בשביל החול, אלא יאמר ננוח כי
>   שבת היום". וכן כתבו האחרונים (מ"א רצ, א; א"ר ב; שועה"ר ו; מ"ב ד).
>
> הרבה פוסקים כתבו שהאיסור לומר שישן כדי שיהיה לו כוח לעשות במוצ"ש דבר
>   שאסור לעשות בשבת, אפילו אם הוא דבר מצווה, כגון לכתוב ספר תורה. אבל כדי
>   ללמוד במוצ"ש – מותר. וכ"כ אז נדברו ד, מו; אור לציון ג, יח, יא; אבני
>   ישפה ו, פו, ב; בירור הלכה זילבר ד, עמ' רלב.
>
> אמנם בפניני הלכה שבת כב, טו, כתבתי בטעם דין זה, שהוא כדי שלא לבזות את
>   השבת "שעושה בה הכנה לחול", ועיין בהרחבות שם כב, טז, א, שבזה שאמר כך
>   זלזל בשבת שהקדיש מזמנה היקר והמקודש כדי להתכונן לחול. וכך ביאר בפס"ת
>   רצ, ד, את דעות הא"ר ופמ"ג ׁ(אמנם צ"ע על דבריו). והורה הרב אליהו שאסור
>   לומר בשבת שהוא הולך לישון אפילו לצורך לימוד בליל שבועות (מאמר מרדכי
>   למועדים ולימים עמ' 171, לח).
>
> **> למעשה כתבתי שלכתחילה עדיף להחמיר, מפני שנכון להדר בכבוד שבת. אבל הרוצה
>   להקל רשאי "הואיל ועיקר האיסור הוא להתכונן בשבת לדבר שיש בו חילול שבת,
>   ובלימוד אין מעשה שאסור בשבת. וגם אין בדיבור זה כל כך פגיעה בכבוד השבת,
>   הואיל והוא לצורך מצווה".**

After discussing the issue and the sources, Rabbi Melamed writes that it is preferable to be stringent out of respect to shabbos. But if one wishes to be lenient, he may nap on shabbos with the stated intention of having energy to learn shavuos night, as the main prohibition of prepeartion is only regarding things that are prohibited on Shabbos itself, and there is no prohibition involved in learning Torah...

Comment: He seems to be talking about the verbal declaration "I'm doing this for after Shabbos" not the act of sleeping itself which it sounds like would be completely fine...

Comment: Baruch Hashem, this is allowed. I'm exhausted just from reading all the above ;-)

Comment: You are resting at a time you are tired, to prepare yourself to study Torah better. Perhaps that is why you can be lenient.